# how to send email notification dynamically in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I need to send email notification to my client dynamically when i receive any order from client. the email ID should be fetched from the database and should send the mail to that email ID. The text or content for the email Id will be fixed.

Comment: Read the guide: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1017/Retrieving-Your-Data
& http://book.cakephp.org/view/1286/Sending-a-basic-message

Answer (score 0):

From the Cake manual: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1286/Sending-a-basic-message

Create a default.ctp file in /app/views/layouts/email/text called default.ctp containing

```
<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
```

Create a default.ctp file in /app/views/elements/email/text called new_order.ctp containing

```
Dear <?php echo $user['User']['firstname'] ?>,
Thank you for your order.
```

Add a function similar to this one to the controller which deals with your orders:

```
<?php
function _sendNewUserMail($id) {
    $User = $this->User->read(null,$id);
    $this->Email->to = $User['User']['email'];
    $this->Email->subject = 'Order Confirmation';
    $this->Email->replyTo = 'support@example.com';
    $this->Email->from = 'Cool Web App <app@example.com>';
    $this->Email->template = 'new_order';
    $this->set('User', $User);
    $this->Email->send();
}
?>
```

Call this method when saving a new order.